# "Suggestions as to how to" vs "suggestions how to"

Tags: word-choice, phrases

Which should I write?

> He has made several suggestions ***as to how to*** improve the situation.
>
> He has made several suggestions ***how to*** improve the situation.

Comment: "several suggestions **for** how to improve the situation."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say *several suggestions for improving the situation*.

Your form with *as to* I find grammatical, but a bit stilted; and with just *how* I find barely grammatical, though I would not be surprised to hear it in informal speech.

Comment: He suggested improvements for the situation

Answer (score 1):

I think *as to* is a form of [hedge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_%28linguistics%29) intended to downplay the "scope" of his proposals. In such contexts, *as to* (and *on*) are commonly used to mean *concerning, relating to, regarding*.

Thus the first version could imply his proposals related to *the general subject of* improvements. Feasibly some of the proposals concerned, for example, dealing with possible side-effects.

The second implies all his proposals were *specifically intended to produce* improvements.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go with either. I'd rephrase it, slightly, as one of these, depending upon the verb tense you need:

> He suggested several ways to improve the situation.

Or

> He has suggested several ways to improve the situation.

I also would substitute something more specific for "the situation" unless the context has already made it clear.